Use symbol address to generate page table entry
I am working on writing a static paging setup for a custom bare-metal ARM system. ARMv7a uses two-level paging, where entries in a top-level page table can point to a second-level table. I have a top-level table and a couple of second-level tables that I need to link together, both implemented in the same .S file and same section.
The "link entry" in the top-level table should have this value:
(second_level_table_addr & 0xfffffc00) | 0x9 -- this takes the base address of the second-level table, and clears the low bits and replaces them with some configuration bits (see ARMv7a manual B3.5.1 for details).
My question is: can I use the symbol for the second-level table to generate the link entry in the top-level table, after relocation? If I try to write an expression like .word (second_level_table_sym & 0xfffffc00) | 0x9, I get the following error: invalid operands (.boot_data and *ABS* sections) for &.
Right now what I'm doing is manually setting absolute addresses for the second-level tables and hard-coding them in the link entries. This works, but I feel like it will be difficult to maintain as the mappings become more complicated, and in general I would like to leave binary layout to the toolchain as much as possible. This would also be pretty easy to fix up at runtime, but unfortunately the tables will be stored in read-only memory and so that isn't possible.
As I understand it, the address of second_level_table_sym is not known when assembling the individual file (the point where I get the error), but it is known at final link time after relocation. Is there a way to get the assembler (GNU arm-eabi-none-as) to use that knowledge to generate the table entry I want?

As you say, the assembler would need to pass that information to the linker and it can't because there is no such relocation type.

You could have second_level_table_sym aligned to 1k then the & 0xfffffc00 would not be needed and the | 0x9 could be done with + 0x9 which can be relocated.

Alternatively, you can build the address in a linker script.

@Jester's approach of changing OR to ADD works, since the second-level table addresses are required to be aligned to >1k anyway. Is there documentation somewhere describing the operations that are compatible with relocations?

Basically just addition. The various relocation types are for the different addressing modes and sizes. They are listed in the ELF ABI spec

If everything is statically linked, then the whole base section is aligned to 4k to 32k depending on TTBCR.  A linker assert can be used to check this is the case and the & operation is not needed.  You have to know the physical location because your linker file must position it.  It is not clear what you gain by not using address constants in the assembler instead of symbols.  For a vast majority of code, this is not true, but MMU tables are an exception.  Hiding table alignment will hide mistakes that only brick a device, with resulting head scratching.

Use a relocation. Let the assembler emit the raw address of the second-level table and let the linker apply the mask and configuration bits.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
